# PHP mail() Sending 2 Emails instead of 1

Tags: php, email

I've got a form I have created that is just a simple form with a text box and submit button. The text box is for an email address that an email will be sent to.

Here's my code:

```
//Get First Name Value
    if($is_logged_id && isset($user_data['FirstName'])) $first_name = $user_data['FirstName'];
    //Get Last Name Value
        if($is_logged_id && isset($user_data['LastName'])) $last_name = $user_data['LastName'];?>

    <?php
        //Get Phone Number
        if($is_logged_id && isset($user_data['Phones'][0]->Number)) $phone_number = $user_data['Phones'][0]->Number;?>

    <?php
        //Get Last 4 digits of phone number
        $last_four = substr($phone_number, -4);
        //Add Phone Number to last name
        $ref_code = $last_name . $last_four;
    ?>

    <?php

    //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
    if (isset($_REQUEST['refemail']))  {

        $email_from = $first_name . $last_name . "<" . $user_data['EmailAddress'] . ">";

        // Headers
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";

        //Email information
        $refemail = $_REQUEST['refemail'];
        $subject = $first_name;

        //send email
        mail($refemail, $first_name , $refcode , $headers);


        //Email response
        echo "<p style='padding: 10px;'>Email Response</p>";
    }

    //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
    else  {

        ?>

        <form method="post">
            <label for="refemail" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 text-left ">Email Address:</label>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
                <input name="refemail" type="text" size="50" class="form-control" /><br />
                <input type="submit" class="ref-btn" value="Submit" />
            </div>

        </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Everything is working exactly the way I want it to, except it is sending two emails that are exactly the same instead of just one. I've done some searching around and I can't find anything that solves my problem.

I've tried adding the following below the mail() function:

```
exit("sent");
```

It still sends two emails.

Is there something wrong with my code or could this be an issue with my host?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using js/ajax, a seperate function, or is that your full and exact code with nothing else added that you're not showing us?

Comment: Possibly two requests are coming to the server. That may be, as Fred suggested, because both AJAX and the normal submit click are hitting the server? Try adding a random number to the email body to see if the two emails differ or if they're duplicates.

Comment: you're also using 5 parameters in `mail()` instead of the usual 4. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php `bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )` - `, $first_name , $refcode ,` is what is at fault here. Read the manual; your headers are incorrect.

Comment: That's all the code I've added for now. I added random numbers to email body and they were two different numbers in each email.

Comment: I'm not actually using 5 parameters, that was a typo when I was making the post. I updated my original post now.

Comment: try changing `mail($refemail, $first_name , $refcode , $headers);` for `mail($refemail, $subject , $refcode , $headers);`

Comment: also `if (isset($_REQUEST['refemail']))  {` to `if (!empty($_REQUEST['refemail']))  {` however, changing all `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`. I don't know why you're using that, you've specified a post method. `$_REQUEST` is mostly only used when mixing GET and POST requests. Beyond that, I couldn't say.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've made all of those changes and it's still working the same, still sending 2 emails.

Comment: make sure that the script is triggered really once. Enable mail.log in php.ini. Also check smtp-server logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the form submit twice, after you refresh the page or you submit the form then refresh.

Here `echo "<p style='padding: 10px;'>Email Response</p>";`, if refresh, here you will see just one 'Email Response'.

Here is to prevent the refresh submit(Jquery):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //then do the submit.
});
```

Or
you can just replace button type for testing

```
<button type="button">
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------

Example of Ajax Post data:

In the **form.php**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<form method="post" id='form'>
   <label for="refemail" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 text-left ">Email Address:</label>
   <input name="refemail" id='refemail' type="text" size="50" class="form-control" /><br />
   <input type="submit" class="ref-btn" value="Submit" />
</form>      

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        data = {
            refemail: $('#refemail').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: './sendemail.php',
            dataType: "html",
            timeout: 50000, 
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);    
            },
            error: function(request, status, err) {}
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

In the **sendemail.php**:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['refemail'])){
            echo $_REQUEST['refemail'];
            //here do the send email 
        }else{
            echo 'No email';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that code and now it's only sending one email. However, I'm not sure I'm implementing this correctly, because now I get an error that all my variables are undefined and the email is coming from an unknown sender. Would I just put my form after the //then do submit line?

Comment: @ThomasSpade It seems like that you go to this form page and still remember the `$_REQUEST['refemail']`, so it will send the email. I don't know why with less code. In the `//then do the submit`, should be the post data method. If  you don't want to send by js, you can try `unset($_REQUEST['refemail']);` after send email.

Comment: I'd like to use JS, but I'm still not understanding how to make it send the email.

Comment: I tried adding unset($_REQUEST['refemail']); after send mail and that worked, but now the message stating that the email was sent doesn't display. It just reloads the page.